# How can I round up a number using c#?

Tags: c#

I have written a code which asks for a towns population and displays the final population, taking into account the growth factor after several years.

I have tried using the following line:

```cs
int rounded = Convert.ToInt32(final_population);
```

to try round up the final population value but it is not working. The output screenshot attached is supposed to display the final population as `26892` but keeps displaying `26891` and I am unsure how to change this? I have tried using the Math.Round and Math.Ceiling(final_population);  function too but cannot get it to work either.

[image]

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Keep the following line intact 
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");

            // Insert your solution here.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the simulation period (whole years):");
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (years < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Simulation cancelled: no years.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of towns:");
            }

            int town = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (town < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Simulation cancelled: no towns.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= town; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the town:");

                string name;
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the initial population of the town:");

                int intial_population = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the growth rate of the town:");

                Decimal growth = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                double value;
                value = (double)(Decimal)Math.Pow((double)growth, years);

                Decimal final_population = (int)(intial_population * value);
                int rounded = Convert.ToInt32(final_population);

                Console.WriteLine("The population of {0} goes from {1} to {2} with growth factor {3} after {4} years.", name, intial_population, final_population, growth, years);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: What is the input value here? `26891` is whole number. What's your idea of round number here? can you share some example inputs and expected outputs? Which screen shot you are mentioning about?

Comment: So searching for "rounding in C#" didn't present you with a solution? If I search that on Google, I immediately find the solution in the first two results.

Comment: @Chetan Sorry forgot to attach the screenshot but should be up there now! The input values are the initial population, years and growth factor and from rearranging the growth factor equation the final population is found which is the 26891. However the calculated value is originally 26891.87085 but shows as 26891 but I need to round it up to 26891. Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama i had tried that and would not have posted the question if i could have a found a solution to the question on google.

Comment: @JohnWu I had tried using Math.Ceiling(final_population);  but it still gives me the same output

Comment: did you try testing `Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(26891.87085));`? does it still outputs `26891`?

Comment: _" I have tried using the Math.Round and Math.Ceiling(final_population);"_ - You're assigning an integer (maths word for "whole number") value to `final_population`. You're throwing away the fractional value at this stage. It's not possible to then "round" the value if you already have a whole number, right?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama exactly, THAT is the real problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Can you see if you can replace this line:

```
Decimal final_population = (int)(intial_population * value);
```

With this?

```
Decimal final_population = (decimal)Math.Ceiling(intial_population * (double)value);
```

The `Math.Ceiling()` method takes a double value as input and rounds it up to the nearest integer greater than or equal to the input. In this case, we convert the value of `intial_population` * value to a double, round it up using `Math.Ceiling()`, and then convert the result back to a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

@justDLight answer can help but is not right and doesn't explain the problem.

You don't need Ceiling, you have to check the conversion. You are making the conversion to `int` before put it on the decimal, and the conversion is round down because is working with Banking System.

You can use `Math.Round` with a correct result if you correct your conversion.

Check this code and this fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXvnDq

```
          Decimal growth = 1.087M;
          int years = 8;
          double value;

          value = (double)(Decimal)Math.Pow((double)growth, years);
          Decimal final_population = (int)(13797 * value);
          int rounded = Convert.ToInt32(final_population);
        
        Console.WriteLine("ROUNDED VAR: " + rounded);
        Console.WriteLine("final_population: " + final_population);
        Console.WriteLine("without conversion: " + 13797 * value);
        Console.WriteLine("with round to 2 decimals: " + Math.Round(13797 * value,2));
        Console.WriteLine("with round to 0 decimals: " + Math.Round(13797 * value,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to completely eliminate decimal part when converting to int from decimal values :  use (int)value  typecast

If u want to get the next whole number : use Math.Ceiling(..)

If u want to get the previous whole number : use Math.Floor(..)

If value< 0.5 , Convert.toInt32 will round to previous whole number,
If value>=0.5, Convert.toInt32 will round to next whole number

Hope this helps in future as well :)